# How to create a link to a user's profile page

Tags: users, links, profiles

I've created a user list for all the customers who registered on my website. When a outside user (or guest) browse my website and want to view the profile of a specific user, they should be able to click on the user's name and then should be redirected to the profile page of that user. I've managed to set everything up but the link points me to an author page and should point me to the PROFILE page of the user.

Code inside `functions.php`:

```
function userlist() {
    global $wpdb;

    $users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users WHERE display_name <> 'admin' ORDER BY display_name");

    foreach ($users as $user ) {

        echo "<li>";
        // GETTING USER AVATAR
        echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
        the_author_meta('user_nicename', $user->ID);
        echo "/\">";
        echo get_avatar($user->ID);
        echo "</a>";
        // DISPLAY USER-NAME
    echo '<div>';
    echo "<a href=\"".get_user_meta('user_url');
    the_author_meta('user_firstname', $user->ID); // points to wishlist url -> seems like it searches for name 
    echo "/\">";
    the_author_meta('user_lastname', $user->ID); // display name
    echo "</a>";
```

I've changed the `// DISPLAY USERNAME` part a bit. When I hover over the username, the link displayed reads: wordpress/user-list/username but when I click on the username it redirects me to the user's wedding registry page which is: `http://example.com/wishlist/romualdo-and-heidis-wishlist/`

The good new is it point somewhere but it needs to go to the user's public profile page. What am I missing in the code to redirect it to profile instead of the wishlist page?

The `functions.php` part where I use query var so that WP catches my custom `/user/username` url:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpleet_rewrite_add_var' );
function wpleet_rewrite_add_var( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'user';
    return $vars;
}

add_rewrite_tag( '%user%', '([^&]+)' );
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^user/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?user=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpleet_rewrite_catch' );
function wpleet_rewrite_catch()
{
    global $wp_query;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'user', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) {
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/UserList.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: The _backend_ profile page?

Comment: no, a custom frontend profile page

Comment: Search the site for 'endpoint'

Comment: Then look more closely. Unless you want to create every single `/profile/nameOfUser` page you need to have your `profile` page act as an endpoint (or use `$_GET` parameters). If the endpoint is working creating the link is just the URL to the `/profile/` page plus the username.

Comment: thanks - will dig a bit deeper - will this 'endpoint' be an automated process if done correctly creating a unique /profile/nameOfUser for each user?

Comment: Yes, done correctly an endpoint should allow the dynamic pages of the kind I think you want.

Comment: I cant seem to get this working - I've posted my code above - could you please help me with this?

Comment: I've update my comment - please read 'THIS IS MY FUNCTIONS.php CODE' part.

Comment: Now you have introduces a "wedding registry page". It is very hard to tell how all of these components interact.

Comment: @user3119567 Can you give me a sample link of an user's profile page?